com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: 102 ( Java21 )
I am trying to attach an agent to the VM, something like this
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid); vm.loadAgent(agent_jar_path); 
it throws an AgentLoadException with the status code 102.
Stack trace :
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: 102
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:113) ~[jdk.attach:na]
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:124) ~[jdk.attach:na]
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:152) ~[jdk.attach:na]
    at jdk.attach/com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.loadAgent(VirtualMachine.java:538) ~[jdk.attach:na]

int rc = x.returnValue();
            switch (rc) {
                case JNI_ENOMEM:
                    throw new AgentLoadException("Insuffient memory");
                case ATTACH_ERROR_BADJAR:
                    throw new AgentLoadException(
                        "Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute");
                case ATTACH_ERROR_NOTONCP:
                    throw new AgentLoadException(
                        "Unable to add JAR file to system class path");
                case ATTACH_ERROR_STARTFAIL: ( 102 )
                    throw new AgentInitializationException(
                        "Agent JAR loaded but agent failed to initialize");
                default :
                    throw new AgentLoadException("" +
                        "Failed to load agent - unknown reason: " + rc);
            }

based on the primary investigation, understood that agent JAR is loaded but failed to initialize.
Could anyone please help me to fix this? Thanks.

It turned out to be incompatible java version of target machine. Issue is fixed.
